# Generate HMAC keys for a service account to use with Google Cloud Storage Interoperability API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Some tools (for example [fog library](http://fog.io/)) need to use the [Interoperability API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability) to be able to manage objects in Google Cloud Storage buckets. That API uses HMAC authentication.

It's straightforward to generate the HMAC credentials for personal accounts. Here're steps From the [documentation of fog](http://fog.io/storage/):

> get your credentials under the section “Interoperable Access”.

However I cannot figure out how to generate those for service accounts. That is necessary in my case because I'd like to grant access to a bucket to an *application* rather then a *person*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to generate HMAC secrets for service accounts. The sub-optimal solution is to create a dedicated user account for signing. You *can* create signed URLs using service account RSA certificates, but that won't work for HMAC compatibility.

Comment: Google has just announced that HMAC for service accounts is now supported (beta).

Comment: @rlandster Do you happen to have a link to the announcement, or some documentation? I wasn't able to find any references to it.

Comment: There's now documentation available at [Manage HMAC keys for service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/managing-hmackeys).

Comment: This answer is outdated and now wrong. It should be deleted. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523766/google-cloud-storage-how-to-generate-access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-progra/77525259#77525259)