# Google cloud storage: How to generate access_key_id and secret_access_key programatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage

Currently we are using AWS s3 service. We are giving access of bucket to user by sharing access_key_id and secret_access_key with them. below is our flow to generate these keys. example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/IAM/Client.html#create_access_key-instance_method

1. Create new IAM user
2. Generate access key and secret key for the user created in step 1
3. Attache bucket access policy to IAM user created in step 1
4. send the access key and secret key created in step 2 in json response

We are now planning to switch to google cloud storage. I have gone through google cloud storage ruby documentation but can't find documentation on how to generate access_key_id and secret_access_key programmatically so that user can use it to access gcs bucket. Does GCS supports similar functionality?  Does GCS provide alternate option for this?

Answer (score 1):

HMAC keys are legacy and used for interoperability, for example, Amazon S3. HMAC keys require using the XML API.

The current storage API is the Cloud Storage JSON API. New features are added to the JSON API.

I am not aware of a Ruby API to create HMAC keys. You can directly call the XML or JSON API with a Ruby HTTP client.

[Ruby: Simple REST Clients for Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client)

The following examples use the CLI `curl` to demonstrate how to call the APIs. Use those to translate into your Ruby code.

Curl example using the [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-hmac-create):

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/?Action=CreateAccessKey&UserName=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL"
```

Curl example using the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/projects/hmacKeys/create):

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/projects/PROJECT_IDENTIFIER/hmacKeys?serviceAccountEmail=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL"
```

Developer [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token) to obtain the required OAuth Access Token for testing purposes only:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

Example Ruby code to create an OAuth Access Token borrowed from this Stack Overflow [answer](https://require%20%27googleauth%27%20%20authorizer%20=%20Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(%20%20%20json_key_io:%20File.open(path_to_json_file),%20%20%20%20scope:%20%27https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform%27)%20%20%20token%20=%20authorizer.fetch_access_token!):

```
require 'googleauth'

authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open(path_to_json_file), 
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform') 

token = authorizer.fetch_access_token!
```

Ruby documentation for Google OAuth:

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-web.md)